# Como imprimir un resultado y agregar una nueva linea "/n"

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estoy imprimiendo un loop y por cada resultado en el array deberia tener una nueva linea o formatear el array de manera que se genere con una lista formateada

El código es el siguiente:

```
import random

def generar_contrasena():
    mayusculas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
    minusculas = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    simbolos = ['!', '#', '$', '&', '/', '(', ')']
    numeros = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

    caracteres = mayusculas + minusculas + simbolos + numeros

    contrasena = []

    # Añado un bucle más y tu bucle se queda dentro de este
    # Uso _ como nombre de variable para indicar que no se usará el valor
    for _ in range(3):
        # Declaro una variable donde iré almacenando la contraseña que genera el bucle interno
        passwd = ""
        for i in range(32):
            # He simplificado un poco tu lógica en este bucle, ahora passwd es 
            # un string así que no hay necesidad de usar join para unir la lista
            passwd += random.choice(caracteres)
        # Al salir del bucle interno, añado la contraseña generada
        contrasena.append(passwd)
    # Devuelvo el array de contraseñas
    return contrasena
def run():
    contrasena = generar_contrasena()
     # He eliminado el + para evitar la concatenación, cuando se pasan varios
     # parámetros a print, por defecto los imprime separándolos por espacios
    print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ', contrasena  )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()


    #deberia añadir un array donde la contraseña lleve la posición del string para cada una de las contraseñas
    #generadas
```

Aquí esta el array con la imagen que muestra el loop del array:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir cada elemento del array en una nueva líneas podrías recorrer el array e imprimir el elemento.

```
for item in array:
    print(item)
```

Si le queres agregar una nueva linea entre item deberías usar la barra invertida `\n`

```
for item in array:
    print(item + "\n")
```

Comment: print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ', contrasena  ) no agregas un salto de linea con el print(item + "\n") si ya tiene un segundo parametro ?

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción a la proporcionada por @favcau es usar el método de los strings `.join()`. Este método une los elementos de la lista con los caracteres inciados, en este caso **saltos de linea.** El `print()` de tu código quedaría así:

```
print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ', "\n".join(pwd for pwd in contrasena))
```

*(he puesto solo esta parte, para no poner todo el código y hacer legible la respuesta)*

**Salida:**

```
Tu nueva contraseña es:  gG/E&$FE/4b2350dBF8$&)D4E$4a2Fgf
AGc74AA1FB86cD7#Gg9)&$&!f/8)B#A2
2543d)dc(!!!!&9a0(!A3gBf8#Gb61fC
```

Puedes quedarlo **más bonito añadiendo tabuladores:**

```
print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ', "\n\t\t\t".join(pwd for pwd in contrasena))
```

**Salida:**

```
Tu nueva contraseña es:  C6e20B4!d0FGG779CC5$7FA$)G5Dd326
                         26$3931655f86)!cD!$ADcd4!B8B//6F
                         7&&C3dfeG17$5f#3$a1!g7d$F9ba49Bc
```